# How to compare boost::variant in order to make it a key of std::map?

Tags: c++, boost, stdmap, boost-variant

How to compare boost::variant in order to make it a key of std::map ?
Seems that operator<() is not defined for boost::variant

Answer (score 5):

**EDITED TO FIX ERROR APPLYING BOOST::APPLY_VISITOR**

You can create a binary visitor for your variant, and then use boost::apply_visitor to create a comparator for your map:

```
class variant_less_than
    : public boost::static_visitor<bool>
{
public:

    template <typename T, typename U>
    bool operator()( const T & lhs, const U & rhs ) const
    {
            // compare different types
    }

    template <typename T>
    bool operator()( const T & lhs, const T & rhs ) const
    {
            // compare types that are the same
    }

};
```

You'll probably need to overload `operator()` for each possible pair of types, as apposed to using the templated `operator(const T &, const U &)`.  Then you'd need to declare your map like this:

```
class real_less_than
{
public:
  template<typename T>
  bool operator()(const T &lhs, const T &rhs)
  {
    return boost::apply_visitor(variant_less_than(), lhs, rhs);
  }
};

std::map<boost::variant<T, U, V>, ValueType, real_less_than> myMap;
```

Edit: for what it's worth, `operator<()` is defined for `boost::variant` however it's defined as:

```
bool operator<(const variant &rhs) const
{
  if(which() == rhs.which())
    // compare contents
  else
    return which() < rhs.which();
}
```

which I'm assuming is not what you want.

Comment: oh, thank you. operator<() did not work for my variant as it is defined with boost::make_recursive_variant<>, not with regular boost::variant<>
I will copy the code from regular boost::variant<>

Comment: @user222202 - see my edit.  You can't call boost::apply_visitor in the template list for map.  You're going to need to create a function object that applies the visitor.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can pass a comparator to the map. Please see http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Map.html for an example on how to write a comparator.